# Join gives incorrect sum

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to write a select statement gathering one row for each name. Expected output is hence:

Name=Al, Salary=30, Bonus=10

Table_1

```
Name   Salary
Al     10
Al     20
```

Table_2

```
Name  Bonus
Al    5
Al    5
```

How do I write that?
I try to:

```
Select t1.Name, SUM(t1.Salary), SUM(t2.Bonus) FROM table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 
ON t1.Name=t2.Name
Group By 1
```

I get bonus 20 instead of 10 as bonus. That is probably because there are two rows in t1 from which the bonus is summed up. How can I modify my function in order to get the correct bonus?

Comment: A hint, do `select * from table_1 t1 LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.Name=t2.Name`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group the tables separately by employee, then join them:

```
SELECT t1.Name, Salary, Bonus
FROM (
  SELECT Name, SUM(Salary) Salary
  FROM table_1
  GROUP BY Name
) t1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT Name, SUM(Bonus) Bonus
  FROM table_2
  GROUP BY Name
) t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name
```

Comment: You need to qualify name in the select list.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a subquery like this:

```
declare @salary table (Name varchar(100), value int)
declare @bonus table (Name varchar(100), value int)

insert into @salary
values ('al', 10)

insert into @salary
values ('al', 20)

insert into @bonus
values ('al', 5)

insert into @bonus
values ('al', 5)


select s.Name, sum(value) as Salary, Bonus
from @salary s JOIN 
(
    select Name, sum(value) as Bonus
    from @bonus 
    group by Name 
) b on b.name = s.Name
group by s.Name, b.Bonus
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  coalesce(t1.name,t2.name) name, 
  coalesce(sum(t1.salary),0) salary_total, 
  coalesce(sum(t2.bonus),0) bonus_total
FROM 
  (select name, sum(salary) salary from salary_table group by 1) t1
FULL OUTER JOIN 
  (select name, sum(bonus) bonus from bonus_table group by 1) t2
ON (t1.name=t2.name)
GROUP BY 1
;
```